# disable right click option in asp.net chart image

Tags: asp.net, charts

We are have a asp.net pie chart in our web application. We need to disable the right click option for that chart image. Could any one advise me how to disable right click option for a asp.net chart image.

Comment: You Didn't mention here - are you making website or Windows application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I suggest you** - to Put your `Pie` Chart into one `<div></div>` and `disable` `right click` of that `<div>` as below **Code**

**HTML**

```
<div id="clickID" style="height:250px;width:180px;border:1px solid black;">
    Here Your Pie Chart
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#clickID").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

[You can See Working JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/vo3xesav/)

**See the Updated Link [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/vo3xesav/1/)**

Comment: @Nathiya - have check out the link ??

Comment: remove the alert and checked right click menu is displaying

Comment: @Nathiya - Yes, you are right, I changed the answer and here is the Update Link - http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/vo3xesav/1/

Comment: If answer is useful for you, then `upvvote` and `accept` the answer will helps other to find out the correct solution - Glad to Help you

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this, but you have to attach a different event than you might have imagined. Here is a simple example of how that works in principal.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preventClick(e, showAlerts) {
        if (e.which <= 3 && e.which >= 1) {
            if (showAlerts) {
                switch (e.which) {
                    case 1: alert('Left click'); break;
                    case 2: alert('Middle click'); break;
                    case 3: alert('Right click'); break;
                }
            } else {
                //keeps the event from propagating
                e.preventDefault()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<!--Change the second parameter to false to prevent propagation-->
<input type="button" onmousedown="preventClick(event, true)" />
```

Comment: @Prog It seems we had the same thoughts on this at about the same time :)